# Add New Opportunity from Account subgrid auto-fills every single Account lookup on Opportunity

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Title basically sums it up.

I have an Account screen, with a sub-grid of Opportunities (by the "parentaccountid" field of Opportunity). When I click + Add New on that Opportunity grid, it autofills parentaccountid on the new record form. That's normal.

BUT I also have 5 other Lookups to Account on Opportunity, with different/specific meanings. What's weird is that it's setting ALL of those Lookups to the Account record I started at (Account record that had the Opportunity subgrid where I clicked +).

Is this expected behavior?
Anyway to change this?

I'd expect CRM to only autofill the field that defines the association for that subgrid (i.e. only auto-fill parentaccountid in this case, leave the other 5 Account lookups blank)

Comment: sounds like product design. see my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never experienced this, but I believe this is due to some OOB relationship mapping according to a community thread. [Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/189841/wrong-default-value-for-lookup-field)

Try to find the mapping under N:1 relationships, and if possible remove the mappings. Otherwise you may need to use the Business rule, script or plugin to remove the auto-mapped values.

Edit:

[This explanation](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/267719/mapping-lookup-fields-from-account-to-opportunity) makes sense and it is expected behavior as per product deisgn.

> Since there is an out of the box parental relationship (opportunity_customer_accounts), all those additional account lookups are automatically mapped to that same "parent" (accountid field), and, since they have already been mapped automatically, you can't map them to another field

Comment: Yes I see the "mappings" for the relationship.. but it won't let me delete it, says it's a System AttributeMap. Script or Business Rule might make sense, my concern though is some of these fields are not even on the form, but they're still getting set in the background. That makes me think script or Business Rule won't work (i.e. it would clear the fields on the create form, but after save CRM would set them anyway in the background)

Comment: @DonCheadle try business rule - entity scope. It should work, you can always test it with some test records.

Comment: Thank you for your advice Arun. Something else bout this concerns me, curious your thoughts! When I add a new Account Lookup field to the Opportunity entity... it ADDS a mapping here and again that mapping cannot be deleted, thus adding another field I need to have extra logic for. Do you know how I can prevent adding Lookup fields getting added to Mappings in the first place?

Comment: @DonCheadle that’s not usual behavior, probably oppty has this internal OOB logic. Try any other entity, this should not happen. I guess this cannot be stopped if it’s CRM product behavior

Comment: Thanks Arun. Definitely seems like CRM OOTB has this as special behavior around any/all Account Lookups on Opportunity. FYI - to fix - I'm going to use JavaScript on Opportunity form load, if in Create, blank out all those Account Lookups that weren't expected to be set. This is OK for our scenario since we can assume that someone creating the Opportunity did not want those other Lookups populated.